# Getting drives when multiple windows are installed in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So here is my problem. I am working on something like file transfer code, now I want to list drives which has windows installed in it.
So here is code which I know if there is only one windows is installed in vb,

```
Dim root As string =Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory())
```

But now I want to get list if there are multiple windows installed on different drives, like in C: windows 10 is installed and in D: windows 8 is installed, then I want both C: and D:

So please anyone can help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need this information? What problem are you trying to solve? Just let the user pick a location, don't worry about whether Windows is installed there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic procedure that gets a list of all the drives on your pc and if they contain the Windows directory, they are added to a list.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim DriveList() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives
    Dim WindowsDrives As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub GetWindowsDrives()
        WindowsDrives.Clear()
        For Each drive As DriveInfo In DriveList
            If Directory.Exists(drive.Name & "\Windows") Then
                WindowsDrives.Add(drive.Name)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Cool. Of course this only checks to see if the Windows folder exists. It doesnt make sure that Windows is actually installed on the drive or which version. As I said it's basic, but in most normal cases it should work just fine. Glad to have helped.